# Batch Rename (remove specific character) Files

Tags: windows, batch-rename

I have about 3500 recorded phone calls and they are all labelled

yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_mobilenumber.3gp

I want to remove the underscore from the name so searching through them is easier

How would I do this, i.e which program or caommand is the easiest to do this.

I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Jacks answer: If your files are stored in subfolders, you could use this command.
In Powershell, navigate to the root folder and execute:

```
get-childitem -recurse -Include *.3gp | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_", "") }
```

---

If you prefer a non-command line version, you could use [Rename Master](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/108/)

[image]

Comment: |This utility is quite good, I've used rename programs before and they were so confusing and didn't even come with proper instruction. This one is great! Thumps up!

Comment: How would the script change if it was a "." instead of "_" that I wanted to remove. For eg, if the input file was "yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.mobilenumber.3gp".

Answer (score 4):

Try Powershell:

```
get-childItem *.3gp | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '_','' }
```